# Prevent serializer creating duplicate items (update_or_create on Nested items)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I post via the API, I want the serializer not duplicated a tag if one exists with the same name.

I tried adding "unique" to the model field of "name" in the class Tag but this did not work- it wouldn't allow me to create other Movie's that linked to a tag which exists.

- Check if the field "name" already exists (case **insensitive**).
- If  the tag "name" exists, just create the FK relationship with the
  existing tag name & the new movie
- If the tag "name" doesn't exist, create it

## Models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    taglevel = models.IntegerField("Tag level", blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Whats happening?", max_length=100, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

## Serializers.py

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    taglevel = filters.CharFilter(taglevel="taglevel")

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name', 'taglevel', 'id')

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    info = InfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'tag')

def get_or_create(self, validated_data):
    tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
    task = Task.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
    for tag_data in tags_data:
        task.tag.get_or_create(**tag_data)
    return task
```

The get_or_create doesn't work (trace here: http://dpaste.com/2G0HESS) as it tells me AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.

Comment: Just a recommendation, have a look at django-taggit package. it's a comprehensive tagging solution that I use. It's easy to embed in your app and it'll take away the hassle/problems you may encounter developing your own tagging models. https://github.com/alex/django-taggit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is not suitable as I need to have individual 'taglevel' per tag. I don't believe this is possible using your suggested method. Could you please show me using serilizers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write custom create method for your models. [Here is an example.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: Please show me the code for a custom method for my issue

Comment: Can you update your question with correct code? You say you have issue with many-to-many relations between Movie and Tags model but you are creating records for Task model which is not defined.